# In Mongo DB, how can I update a nested property of a property that can be null

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a MongoDB document with a `settings` field, itself with two nested fields, `selectedSectionIds` and `sectionColors`. `settings` is not an array. I need to update only the `selectedSectionIds` field.

My update builder looks like this:

```
  Builders<Account>.Update.Set(
    "settings.selectedSectionIds",
    sectionIds)
```

And I'm calling `UpdateOneAsync` with nothing more special.

When `settings` is not present in the original document or already contains something, all works well, but when `settings` is null (and it can), I get the following `MongoWriteException`:

> A write operation resulted in an error.
>     cannot use the part (settings of settings.selectedSectionIds) to traverse the element ({settings: null})

How can I update my builder (or class maps/serializers?) to support all scenarios?

(MongoDB C# drivers 2.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot update a property of a `null`. if it was an empty object `{}` it would work.
so my suggestion is to do a bulk update command with 2 steps. where in the first step you check for the null and change it, and in the second step you set the sub property value as needed.

here's an example using **MongoDB.Entities** for brevity:

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Account : Entity
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Settings Settings { get; set; }
        }

        public class Settings
        {
            public string[] SelectedSectionIDs { get; set; }
            public string[] SectionColors { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "127.0.0.1");

            var acc1 = new Account
            {
                Name = "Account One",
                Settings = new Settings
                {
                    SectionColors = new[] { "green", "red" },
                    SelectedSectionIDs = new[] { "xxx", "yyy" }
                }
            }; acc1.Save();

            var acc2 = new Account
            {
                Name = "Account Two",
                Settings = null
            }; acc2.Save();

            DB.Update<Account>()

              .Match(a => a.Settings == null)
              .Modify(a => a.Settings, new Settings())
              .AddToQueue()

              .Match(_ => true)
              .Modify(a => a.Settings.SelectedSectionIDs, new[] { "aaa", "bbb" })
              .AddToQueue()

              .Execute();

        }
    }
}
```